# Spring Batch - calculate MD5 hash of file names and then write to file

Tags: spring-batch

I've been using spring batch to generate a set of csv files to a specific folder. The final task is required to generate a MD5 hash code of all the files names, this hash is then written to a file in the same folder.

I'm not sure if i should implement this step as a Tasklet only or use a the normal reader, processor and writer configuration.

I know i can easily add all the files names to a list, which could be passed any of these object types.

I know i can implement the code for generating the MD5 hash in a processor or tasklet.

I'm not sure how i can pass the generated hash code to a FlatFileWriter?

If i do use the standard step pattern, what should my Reader be configured to do?

I appreciate this question doesn't have strict technical answer but i'd appreciate any advise on how i can best use Spring Batch in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

1. `ItemReader<Resource>` to pass all filenames to process as Resource
2. `Processor<Resource,MD5>` to calculate hash in the **fastest** way
3. `FlatFileItemWriter<MD5>` to write hash to output file
   but you "lose" restartability because you can restart from a whole file and not from the middle (for example) : this solution can be easy to implement if files are small

Using

1. a `MultiResourceItemReader` with a custom `ItemReader<MD5ResourceBean>` as
   delegate
2. custom `ItemProcess<MD5ResourceBean,MD5ResourceBean>`
3. custom `ItemWriter<MD5ResourceBean>` that compute total MD5 value
   for a certain resource (stored in execution-context as well as the current resource name) and when
   passing to next resource write MD5 value of previous resource to
   your file

`MD5ResourceBean` is defined with this properties:

- `Resource resource`: current resource under md5 calculation
- `byte[] buffer`: last chunk of file read
- `MD5 bufferMD5`: MD5 of last buffer (this is calculated by processor)

This solution can be a bit complex but can give full restartability and can works well with large files,too!

As third option a `SystemCommandTasket` if you already have an external program that can process all files in one shot and write results to file.

I hope I was helpful (and clear, English is not my native language).